# What are dirty writes? What happens if they are not allowed?

Tags: database, transactions, rdbms, isolation-level, dirty-write

I read about database isolation levels and transactional phenomena.
Dirty reads are obvious but I don't understand dirty writes.

All descriptions of dirty write say something like:

> A dirty write is when a process save[s to] a file data that has already been changed on disk by another process. The last process will then overwrite the data of the first one. https://gerardnico.com/data/property/dirty_write

Some other descriptions use examples to demonstrate a dirty write but not what will happen to solve that. https://esb-dev.github.io/mat/IsoLevel.pdf

This is a dirty write from the example:

> 1. Saldo starts with 100
> 2. T2 begins: update Acct set Saldo = 200 where Acct = 1
> 3. T1 begins: update Acct set Saldo = 250 where Acct = 1
> 4. T1 commits => Saldo=250
> 5. T2 commits => Saldo=200

I don't know what will happen when the isolation level does not allow dirty writes.

- **T1 fails at commit** because the change of T2 isn't comitted at that time
- T1 commits successfully and **T2 commit fails** because T1 (not committed yet) overwrites that change
- T1 and T2 commit successfully but **T1 wins** silently (saldo 200 instead of 250)

I don't know what I should expect from transaction management. The example, modified:

1. Saldo starts with 100
2. T1 begins: update Acct set Saldo = 200 where Acct = 1
3. T2 begins: update Acct set Saldo = 250 where Acct = 1
4. T2 commits => Saldo=?
5. T1 commits => Saldo=?

Do we have a dirty write here? And what is the result if dirty write is allowed?

- Saldo = 250 because the last update wins
- Saldo = 200 because the last commit wins

I have an additional question about Java/Spring JPA/Hibernate: Are write statements not sent to the database unless hibernate does a commit? Some isolation levels and phenomena only make sense if all statements are always transmitted instantly to the database.

Comment: Start by researching by reading an authoritative reviewed source--a DMBS manual or documentation or a textbook. Not web sites. Especially not web sites with bad grammar. Otherwise you are just asking us to (re)write yet another presentation. Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. Ask just 1 question the 1st place you get stuck. If you are testing using a DBMS then tag with it, because SQL isolation levels are a specification that can be satisfied differently. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general transactions prevent dirty writes by locking rows that will be written to until the end of the transaction. This means that neither transaction will fail, it's just that the second write will be delayed until the first transaction is finished. I don't think there are any isolation levels that don't do this.

So when you think about dirty writes you can imagine not having any isolation. In your first example I would expect that Saldo's final account to be 250 because the update to 200 was overwritten.

Note that it's not necessarily a problem for one transaction to overwrite the write of another transaction. Even if we imagine that the two transactions ran serially (i.e. everything in the first transaction completes before the second transaction starts) and therefore completely isolated we still expect one transaction to overwrite the other transaction.

I think a better example of a dirty write would be if transaction A and B both try to write to rows 1 and 2, but transaction A writes last to row 1 and transaction B writes last to row 2. Then you will see a result that doesn't match our expectation of isolation.

For a concrete example you can imagine you have two rows representing first and second place of a race. The first transaction set racer 1 in first and racer 2 in second place. Moments later a second transaction wants to update to put racer 2 in first place and racer 1 in second place. If dirty writes are possible then you could end up with racer 1 (or racer 2) in both first and second place slots.

As I mentioned already you can fix this problem by using transaction of any isolation level which will lock rows that are being written to from being written to by any other transactions until the changes are committed.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty writes ARE not allowed. The problem with your examples is that the 2nd transaction which tries to update a row commits first. But in reality this is not the case. The first update statement blocks the row till the end of the first transaction. And the 2nd transaction should wait.

Answer (score -1):

- **Dirty write** is that a transaction updates or deletes (overwrites) the uncommitted data which other transactions insert, update or delete.

If **dirty write** is not allowed and **T1(Transaction 1)** fisrt updates a row, then the row is locked by **T1** so **T2(Transaction 2)** needs to wait to update the same row until **T1** commits(unlocks the same row). ***T2** can still update other unlocked rows except the row locked by **T1**.

I could experiment **not-allowd dirty write** with **MySQL** and **2 command prompts** as shown below. But, I couldn't experiment **allowed dirty write** with **MySQL** even though I set `READ UNCOMMITTED` which is the most loose transaction isolation level. *Basically, **dirty write** is not allowed with all isolation levels in many databases.

For **"not-allowd dirty write" experiment**, I set **`READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level**:

```
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

And, I created **`person` table** with **`id`** and **`name`** as shown below.

#### `person` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** |
| **2** | **David** |

Now, I did **these steps below** with **MySQL queries**:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`UPDATE person SET name = 'Tom' WHERE id = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates `David` to `Tom` so this row is locked by T1 until T1 commits.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`UPDATE person SET name = 'Lisa' WHERE id = 2;`** **ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction** | **T2 cannot update `Tom` to `Lisa` before T1 commits because this row is locked by T1 so error occurs.** #### *Dirty write is not allowed. |
| **Step 5** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 6** |  | **`UPDATE person SET name = 'Lisa' WHERE id = 2;`** | **Now, T2 can update `Tom` to `Lisa` because T1 has already committed(unlocked this row).** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |

Finally, I'm not exaxtly sure about what happens if **dirty write** is allowed but I think if **dirty write** is allowed, the last updated data should be used whether it's committed first or last.